Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses' react native
At the moment I tried to compile my app the following issue runs, I add a new component for other team to my project and It looks like that use a repated group as mine, how can I handle it?
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable > Duplicate class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver found in modules firebase-iid-20.1.5.aar -> jetified-firebase-iid-20.1.5-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.1.5) and firebase-messaging-23.4.1.aar -> jetified-firebase-messaging-23.4.1-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.4.1) Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>. * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 11s.

I try to exclude one of this groups, addding the following implementation to app/build.gradle but it does not work. the compilation still throws me the same issue
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.4.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-iid'
}

I want to exclude one of these group and compile it
build.gradle


buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.22"
        RNNKotlinVersion = kotlinVersion
    }
     subprojects { subproject ->
        afterEvaluate{
            if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
                android {
                    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
                }
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
         mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
          url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenLocal()
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
             maven {
                 url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            }
            maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
            }
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
            maven {
                url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
                authentication {
                    basic(BasicAuthentication)
                }
                credentials {
                    username = '******'
                    password = '**************'
            }
        }
        maven {
            credentials {
                username '************'
                password '************'
            }
            url '************'
        }
  }}
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"



app/build.gradle


apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"


import com.android.build.OutputFile

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"


react {

}

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.*******"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.*******"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.4"
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            v1SigningEnabled false
            v2SigningEnabled false
            enableV3Signing true
            enableV4Signing true
        }
            release {
            storeFile file('******')
            storePassword '********'
            keyAlias '*******'
            keyPassword '********'
            v1SigningEnabled false
            v2SigningEnabled false
            enableV3Signing true
            enableV4Signing true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation project(':react-native-orientation')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'
    implementation project(':react-native-material-letter-icon')
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)




Without checking gradle it's difficult for anyone to tell why its happening, so can you post project level build.gradle and app build.gradle?

I already attached, thanks for your comment

Where you have declared library com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging I can't find it in any of the gradle files.

I do not declare it, this is a react native project, I install this dependency in my package.json
